# Remove trailing .0 from strings of entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, regexp-replace, character-trimming

Hi I would like to remove all ".0" at the end of a string for an entire DataFrame and I need it to be an exact match.

Let's make an example df:

```
a      b      c
20     39.0   17-50
34.0   .016.0   001-6784532
```

The desired output:

```
a      b      c
20     39     17-50
34     .016   001-6784532
```

I tried using `replace` but it didn't work for some reason (I read maybe because replace only replaces entire strings and not substrings?). Either way, if there is a way it can work I'm interested to hear about it because it would work for my dataframe but I feel it's less correct in case I'll have values like .016.0 beacause then it would also replace the first 2 characters.

Then I tried sub and rtrim with regex `r'\.0$'` but I didn't get this to work either. I'm not sure if it's because of the regex or because these methods don't work on an entire dataframe. Also using rtrim with `.0` didn't work because it removes also zeros without a dot before and then 20 will become 2.
When trying sub and rtrim with regex I got an error that dataframe doesn't have an attribute `str`, how is that possible?

Is there anyway to do this without looping over all columns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['20', '34.0'],
    'b': ['39.0', '.016.0'],
    'c': ['17-50', '001-6784532']
})

df = df.replace(r'\.0$', '', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Optional [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) if the columns are not already `str`:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace(r'\.0$', '', regex=True)
```

Before:

```
      a       b            c
0    20    39.0        17-50
1  34.0  .016.0  001-6784532
```

After:

```
    a     b            c
0  20    39        17-50
1  34  .016  001-6784532
```

---

`rtrim`/`rstrip` will not work here as they don't parse regex but rather take a list of characters to remove. For this reason, they will remove all `0` because `0` is in the "list" to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally replace; Use np.where().

```
df['b']=np.where(df['b'].str.contains('\.\d+\.'),df['b'].str.replace(r'\.\d+$','', regex=True), df['b'])



    a     b            c
0  20.0  39.0        17-50
1  34.0  .016  001-6784532
```

That is, where we have `.digit(s).`, replace `.\digit(s)` at the end

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand how this solves my problem. It still gives you .0 behind the rest of the dataframe and even in column b itself in the first row. And what do you mean with the last sentence? I see it's not being used in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to export the DataFrame to a CSV (or other types), you can use the parameter [float_format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) from Pandas to eliminate all trailing zeros from the entire DataFrame.

```
df.to_csv(path_to_file.csv, float_format='%g')
```

'%g' and other formats [explanation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/format.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).